# Enhancing the display of a particular column in a WPF grid view

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have some user admin functionality in a WPF app that I'm currently writing and would like to make it a bit more intuitive for the end user

I'd like to be able to provide some kind of means of easily editing the list of roles a given user belongs to. At the moment the grid is filled as a result of binding to a `List<ApplicationUser>`

`ApplicationUser` is my own class defined as:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
        public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
        public string GivenName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string UserPhone { get; set; }
        public string NtLoginName { get; set; }
        public List<Role> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }
}
```

As can be seen the roles that the user is in are held in a `List<Role>`. `Role` is my own class defined as:

```
public class Role
{
   public Guid RoleId;
   public string RoleName;
   public string RoleDescription;
}
```

The below mockup represents the current state where I just get the roles as a List and through the use of a converter just display the roles as new-line separated strings in the gridview

[image: Current state of gridview]

However this is what I'd like to achieve to make toggling off and on membership of various groups easier.

[image: Desired state of gridview]

Now that I think about it I'll probably have to change the definition of Role to include an IsMember property to facilitate binding on the checkbox but if anybody has a better way I'll welcome that as well. I can change the JOIN type in the sproc so I get back all roles with a query about a particular user and fill the IsMember property accordingly.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: did this ever get solved? I feel from the answer below that it wasn't & I might be able to help out if you still need this.

Comment: @Maverik - no never solved. I was just revisiting it today after a prolonged detour into other areas of the app. I was looking at Tamir Dresher's proposed answer but will work with you if you can...

Comment: Well his idea is right but judging by the given data, it doesn't seem as straight forward, as it might appear from his answer. Is your list of total roles static or does it change over time with new roles being added or old ones removed completely (not just checked or unchecked)?

Comment: An administrator can change the roles and persist them to a DB, I have a method that will get them all from the database. I can then (as per the suggestion below) bind all the roles upon retrieval...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a short piece of code I've whipped up to get you started. I've assumed that you can hydrate `IsMember` property of `Role` class when you create the application user. I've taken the easiest route by having all roles in all users (`enum flags` would have been best but given your data, I'm not sure that's an option without some plumbing). I've used minimal columns to get the idea across. If you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on Roles at least, you can hook up to the notification and persist it back into database when the check-boxes change on front end.

---

**Main Xaml**

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=AllUsers}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding GivenName}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Surname}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationRoles}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Content="{Binding RoleName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsMember, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

**Data Xaml**

```
<x:Array x:Key="AllUsers" Type="Sample:ApplicationUser">
    <Sample:ApplicationUser GivenName="Andrew" Surname="Fuller">
        <Sample:ApplicationUser.ApplicationRoles>
            <Sample:Role RoleName="Administrators" IsMember="True"/>
            <Sample:Role RoleName="Shift Analysts"/>
            <Sample:Role RoleName="Shift Managers" IsMember="True"/>
        </Sample:ApplicationUser.ApplicationRoles>
    </Sample:ApplicationUser>
    <Sample:ApplicationUser GivenName="Anne" Surname="Dodsworth">
        <Sample:ApplicationUser.ApplicationRoles>
            <Sample:Role RoleName="Administrators"/>
            <Sample:Role RoleName="Shift Analysts" IsMember="True"/>
            <Sample:Role RoleName="Shift Managers" IsMember="True"/>
        </Sample:ApplicationUser.ApplicationRoles>
    </Sample:ApplicationUser>
</x:Array>
```

---

**Class definitions**

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public string GivenName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string UserPhone { get; set; }
    public string NtLoginName { get; set; }
    public List<Role> ApplicationRoles { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        ApplicationRoles = new List<Role>();
    }
}

public class Role
{
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string RoleDescription { get; set; }

    public bool IsMember { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Result**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Done and dusted. First impressions were correct - it is an absolutely super answer. Thanks ever so much!

Answer (score 2):

If the Roles column always displays the same list of roles, you can easily bind a ListView to the list of all roles with an ItemTemplate that is built from a CheckBox and a TextBlock.

Then, you can easily bind the IsChecked property of the CheckBox to the User Roles and use a converter that returns True if the role is in the user Roles list.